# Cannot Resolve firebase in my application

Tags: reactjs, firebase

So I'm developing an app using firebase and react, and when I run `npm start` to test the app, I get a lot of errors including this

```
./src/Login.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/Users/.../.../.../.../project/src
```

And this (the full error is too large to show, but here's the end snippet):

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.23.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.23.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is the import statement in Login.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
```

Its important to note that I'm working with friends on this application and they can run this app using `npm start` without any issues and even build and deploy to firebase hosting using the exact same code I have. In addition, I can run the template React app created via `create-react-app` without any issue. Because of this, I thought it was either a problem with my NPM install or my Firebase install, so I re-installed both, but that changed nothing. I'm honestly stuck and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you install it? Like `npm i firebase`

Comment: Yes. I installed it